# How change css :after in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML block:

```
<div class="item" ng-click="toogle()"></div>
```

And CSS style:

```
.item:after {
    content: "\A";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
    border-color: #7da9cd transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -8px;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```

How I can hide style :`after` after each click toggle?

Comment: you can't use `:after` in inline style, so you need to toggle another class and use css stylesheet rules

Comment: Can you share exmaple please?

Comment: use `ng-class` ..see docs

Answer (score 0):

Fix your css, :after isn't ok, and then try something like:

CSS:

```
.item:{
   display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$scope.toggle = function(){

   angular.element('.item').css('display','none');
}
```